# Awesome-WM: Position of context menus with Radical

Tags: awesome-wm

I'm currently trying to make myself familiar with the [Radical menu subsystem](https://github.com/Elv13/radical) of Awesome Window Manager. I want to create a simple menu like the ones you could also make with awful.menu. My code looks like this (of course this is not the complete config file, but the relevant parts of it):

```
local radical = require("radical")

local menu = radical.context {
    style      = radical.style.classic,
    item_style = radical.item.style.arrow_single ,
    layout     = radical.layout.vertical,
}

menu:add_item {text="Item 1"}
menu:add_item {text="Item 2"}
menu:add_item {text="Item 3"}

local menutextbox = wibox.widget.textbox("Menu")
menutextbox:set_menu(menu, "button::pressed", 1)
```

I then include the menutextbox into my wibar. However, when I click on it, the menu always opens in the upper left corner. I tried to set the position manually with menu.x and menu.y, but this didn't change anything. So, how can I change the position of the menu from the corner to the widget which opens it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better report a bug in the project repository with your Awesome version. Given the lack of effort to keep up with the newer Awesome changes, it might very well just be broken for your version.

I have a (local) branch with some newer fixes for Awesome v4.3, but it still has some regressions.